# For-Each Loop, Map<String, Map<String, List<String>>>

Tags: java, swing

How to change the part of my code where is a For-Each Loop. It should work like this

When I'll write "Mark" in the window and click okay (next Alina etc), down below should be displayed:

```
[A]

    [l]
        - Alina
    [d]
        - Adam
[M]

    [a]

         - Mark
```

[image]

public class WordsList extends ArrayList {

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    if (isEmpty()) {
        return "[]";
    }
    return String.format("[%s]\n", stream().collect(Collectors.joining(",")));     
   }
}
```

Test Class

```
private Map<String, Map<String, List<String>>> words = new HashMap<>();
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    String key = ("" + jTextField1.getText().charAt(0)).toUpperCase();
    Map<String, List<String>> firstLevel = words.get(key);
    String value = jTextField1.getText();

    if (firstLevel == null) {
        firstLevel = new HashMap<>();
        words.put(key, firstLevel);
    }

    List<String> secondLevel = firstLevel.get("" + jTextField1.getText().charAt(1));

    if (secondLevel == null) {
        secondLevel = new ArrayList<>();
        firstLevel.put("" + jTextField1.getText().charAt(1), secondLevel);
    }

    secondLevel.add(value);

    jTextArea1.setText("");

    for (String keys : words.keySet()) {
        jTextArea1.append("[" + keys + "]\n");            
        for (String keyss : firstLevel.keySet()) {
            jTextArea1.append("        " + "[" + keyss + "]\n");                
            for (String keysss : secondLevel) {
                jTextArea1.append("           " + "-" + keysss + "\n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am very beginner in Java also, this is my first post

Comment: *"Can somebody help me.."* ..you seem to be looking for a tutor, and this is not the place to ask. If that impression is wrong, post a [mcve] and ask a *specific* question.

Comment: Why are you overriding `ArrayList`'s toString? That is pretty much the default implementation.

Comment: This code seems to be working as expected

Comment: No is not. For example when I put Alina, [A] its okay and [l] and Alina, then I put Mark, I overwrties [l] to "a" and Alina to "Mark". Only [A] will stay and [M]

Answer (score 2):

> For example when I put Alina, [A] its okay and [l] and Alina, then I put Mark, I overwrties [l] to "a" and Alina to "Mark". Only [A] will stay and [M]

The mistake is in the for loops:

```
for (String keys : words.keySet()) {
    jTextArea1.append("[" + keys + "]\n");            
    for (String keyss : firstLevel.keySet()) { // <-- Here
        jTextArea1.append("        " + "[" + keyss + "]\n");                
        for (String keysss : secondLevel) { // <-- Here
            jTextArea1.append("           " + "-" + keysss + "\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Rather than iterating over `firstLevel` and `secondLevel` (which you've just defined), you should iterate over the the map and list's corresponding entries:

(I'll use `Map.forEach` here since it's a little more concise)

```
words.forEach((c1, map) -> {
    jTextArea1.append("[" + c1 + "]");

    map.forEach((c2, list) -> {
        jTextArea1.append("        " + "[" + c2 + "]");

        list.forEach(name -> jTextArea1.append("           " + "-" + name));
    });         
});
```

Comment: Thank You for response. I Used your code and this is what i got https://naforum.zapodaj.net/d8df4706f6ed.jpg.html.

Comment: @mIeSo There might be some other error that I can't see. [This is what it looks like in my test program](http://ideone.com/iELZel) (at the bottom).

Comment: I will check my code later and I will try to figure out this . I'll let you know

Comment: Its working :) But I did it in different way. http://ideone.com/W0jV8I (Its only part of code so it will not run)